# php require object property to be of given type

Tags: php

Is it possible to create a class/object which requires properties to be of a given type?  For instance, the following would through an exception, warning, error, etc.

```
$bla = new bla();
$bla->integer_only="not an integer";

class bla {
  public $array_only;
  public $string_only;
  public $integer_only;
}
```

Comment: Not if you make it public: if it's private or protected, and can only be set via a setter method, then you can enforce that rule in the setter

Comment: @MarkBaker.  Thanks Mark. Understood with private.  Could it also be enforced if protected?

Comment: If it is protected then the child class could easily ignore the setter methods.

Comment: If the properties are protected, then any child class could bypass the datatype checking..... unless you use `final` to prevent child classes from overriding the setter.... though even then there's nothing to prevent a setter having a different name

Answer (score 1):

We can validate the data type of the value assigned. but we can not force to assign only a specific datatype to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use type hinting in the function parameters so long as the type is not scalar or use the PHP gettype() method in the constructor. Something like this also works;

```
if(is_int($value)){
  // all is good
}
```

Comment: if(gettype($value)!="integer"){
  // throw error here
}

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a base class with your private variables and then public and/or protected setter methods that check the type and throw exceptions as needed.  Consider the following:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    private $intValue;
    private $strValue;
    private $arrayValue;

    protected function setInt($int)
    {
        if(is_int($int)) {
            $this->intValue = $int;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException;
        }
    }

    protected function setString($str)
    {
        if(is_string($str)) {
            $this->strValue = $str;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException;
        }
    }

    protected function setArray(array $arr)
    {
        //No need to check, type hint in method signature will enforce array
        $this->arrayValue = $arr;
    }

    // Be sure to add your getter methods as well!!!!
    // .....
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function setValues($int, $str, $arr)
    {
        $this->setInt($int);
        $this->setString($str);
        $this->setArray($arr);
    }
}

?>
```

The `Foo` class is the parent class and makes sure that only the correct types make it into the private variables.  `Bar` is the child and can use the protected setter methods, but can't assign the types directly.  The following code:

```
$bar = new Bar();
$bar->setValues(0, "We the people...", array("banana", "apple", "orange"));
var_dump($bar);
```

produces:

```
object(Bar)[1]
  private 'intValue' (Foo) => int 0
  private 'strValue' (Foo) => string 'We the people...' (length=16)
  private 'arrayValue' (Foo) => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'banana' (length=6)
      1 => string 'apple' (length=5)
      2 => string 'orange' (length=6)
```

If you do not provide the proper `int`, `string`, or `array` value you will get dinged with a catchable fatal error or an `InvalidArgumentException`.  Basically this will make your code attempt to crash if the rules aren't adhered to.